# How to plot relative frequency histogram with categories having zero proportion or counts in geom_bar() function of ggplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm using `ggplot2` to plot relative frequency histograms comparing proportion of observations for treatment groups by age categories.

Using the following data as an example, where there are zero observations in the Treatment_Group="Treat=0", Age_Group="30+" category:

```
Treatment_Group <- c("Treat=1","Treat=1","Treat=1","Treat=0","Treat=0")   
Proportion <- c(.1,.6,.3,.5,.5)
Age_Group <- c("< 20", "20-29", "30+", "< 20", "20-29")
RelFreq_Data <- data.frame(Treatment_Group, Proportion, Age_Group)
RelFreq_Data
  Treatment_Group Proportion Age_Group
1         Treat=1        0.1      < 20
2         Treat=1        0.6     20-29
3         Treat=1        0.3       30+
4         Treat=0        0.5      < 20
5         Treat=0        0.5     20-29
```

when plotting a bar chart the bar width for the Treatment_Group="Treat=1", Age_Group="30+" category is doubled.

```
ggplot(RelFreq_Data,aes(Age_Group,Proportion,fill=Treatment_Group))+
+   geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image]

Is there a way to add "padding" for categories with zero observations so that the bar widths remain uniform?

Answer (score 1):

You need a row in your data showing the category for which the proportion is 0.

```
Treatment_Group <- c("Treat=1","Treat=1","Treat=1","Treat=0","Treat=0", "Treat=0")   
Proportion <- c(.1,.6,.3,.5,.5, 0)
Age_Group <- c("< 20", "20-29", "30+", "< 20", "20-29", "30+")
RelFreq_Data <- data.frame(Treatment_Group, Proportion, Age_Group)
ggplot(RelFreq_Data, aes(Age_Group, Proportion, fill = Treatment_Group)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

Comment: Rather than change the data frame, you can also use `complete` from the `tidyr` package to add the missing levels. In this case, you would just change the data argument from `RelFreq_Data` to `complete(RelFreq_Data, Treatment_Group, nesting(Age_Group)`.

Comment: Manually adding a row to the data was my first thought, but for large datasets with multiple missing rows this could get tedious.